# Default constructor being called during POST and I lose all model data

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a problem where a form is posting back and the model is being lost.  As soon as the page is posted back .net is calling the default constructor of the object even though the object already exists.

I have 2 actions, one for GET and one for POST

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Quote(string sku, string network, string grade )
        {
            QuoteModel qm = new QuoteModel();
            // build model here
            return View("Quote", qm);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Quote(QuoteModel qm, string grade, string network)
        {
            // update model
            return View("Quote",qm);
        }
```

The GET function works perfectly but as soon as the form is posted, the default constructor is called and I lose all the model data.

My view is like:

```
@model PriceCompare.Models.QuoteModel

    <div class="clarify">
        @if (Model.clarify == true)
        {


            using (Html.BeginForm("Quote", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {

            @Html.DropDownList("network", Model.availableNetworks);
            @Html.DropDownList("grade", Model.grades);

            <button type="submit">Get Quote</button>
            }

        }
    </div>
```

Why is the default contructor being called when there is an existing model to pass back?

I have tried specifying the model in the form like:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Quote", "Home", new { @qm = Model}, FormMethod.Post)
```

If I do this then the default constructor is not being called but `qm` is null.

I've been going round in circles here trying to figure this out.  Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why not naming your POST action differently? should fix the problem...

Comment: @Charlie I just tried changing POST method to "QuoteUpdate()", the default constructor is still called in same way

Comment: try to replace : @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "QuoteUpdate", controllerName: "Home"))

Comment: @Charlie It still calls default constructor of QuoteModel

Comment: can you post your model class? there shouldn't be a constructor in it model is just declaring an object that you will manipulate in controllers

Comment: and you wrote that your post action was used to "update model", Post action is to add something, if you just update something try using "PUT" action

Comment: Post does not magically transfer back to server the whole model. The only data being posted is what you have as values in named inputs (those with name attribute defined) inside the form. So if you had a collection in your form which you use for a dropdown - it is not going to be posted because the whole collection is not a value of the dropdown, just the selected option. You would need to query your DB (presumably) for the collection on post action again

Comment: @Andrei how do I pass the whole model back?  Do I have to serialize it as Json then add to hidden input field?

Comment: @Guerrilla, well, in theory this can be done, something along what you are saying. However this is not a good practice. Do you really need the whole model back, or just entered values/selected ids etc?

Comment: MVC is stateless.. that means that data is not persisted between requests for you, the default constructor is being called because it's a new request and therefore a new object.

Comment: @Andrei There are a few object lists with around a hundred entries.  This data is created in the GET method and isn't saved to a database. I just want to not have to create these arrays again on each postback as it involves external calls.  Shall I just serialize the bits I need and add that to form field?

Comment: @BenjaminPaul Thanks, this is my first MVC project so I am still learning.

Comment: @Guerrilla, if the only reason you are sending these arrays to client is to have them back on post, it might be worth thinking about some storage on the server-side. Have you considered any?

Comment: @Andrei yes you are right, I really should store this in a database otherwise I will be outputting all data for the world to see.  Would storing the data in the session be a viable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by overloading the constructor, and only explicitly calling the second constructor with a boolean parameter set to true.

## Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int NumberRequested { get; set; }

    // This constructor will be called by MVC
    public MyModel()
    {
        RefreshReport();
    }

    // Call this constructor explicitly from the controller
    public MyModel(bool load)
    {
        if (!load)
        {
            return;
        }

        NumberRequested = 10;

        RefreshReport();
    }

    public void RefreshReport()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

## Constructor

```
public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult MyView()
    {
        var myModel = new MyModel(true);

        return View(myModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyView(MyModel myModel)
    {
        myModel.RefreshReport();

        return View(myModel);
    }
}
```